# How to set page load time out in django

Tags: python, django

I tried to set page load time out for Django and I come across two ways and there Problems
In the models I have function that use external module function sometimes that module function calculation time may take more then 1 minute so I want to limit that time

1. with python signal but signal command will not run unless the thread is a main thread
2. after reading the Django documentation I tried to use the TIME_OUT variable in the settings.py but it didn't affect anything

Views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from web.models import SomeClass
instance = SomeClass()

def get_service(request):
    service_instance.some_func()
    return render_to_response('get.html', dic, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
from x import y
temp = y()
class SomeClass():
    def some_func(self):
        temp.do_somthing()
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for webservice project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
#DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
TIME_OUT = 2 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webservice.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webservice.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I want to build time out for the some_func function or better to limit the page load time in django settings 
the main problems is that some_func call another module so i can't use loop while with time.time because after 
If anyone knows the idea or the way to solve this problem I will be very appreciated

I'm using python 2.7 and Django 1.6

Comment: I think you need to do this in the webserver rather than in Django. There is no `TIME_OUT` setting https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/

Comment: so the TIME_OUT variable is Django settings have to relation to page time out ?

Comment: there is no `TIME_OUT` setting

Comment: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/) seek TIMEOUT

Comment: that's a key in the `CACHES` setting dict, for the cache backend